# Коли питання з ukrainian.stackexchange.com почнуть з'являтися в результатах пошуку?

Tags: support

На данний момент запитання з нашого сайту не потрапляють у пошукову видачу [google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=default+value+ukranian+stack+exchange&rlz=1C9BKJA_enUA613UA613&oq=default+value+ukranian+stack+exchange&aqs=chrome..69i57.75915j0j7&hl=ru&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) навіть при явному вказанні джерела. Це пов'язане з закритою бетою? У відкритій беті питання будуть видаватись при пошуку?

Comment: I think it is due to the **Private** Beta, but a brief searching on Meta.SE did not give a specific answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Відповідь проста: під час приватної бети людина, що не залогінилася, не може зайти на наш сайт (на відміну від сайтів після приватної бети, де, здається, не лише зайти без логіну, а й спитати/відповісти без логіну можна).

А гугл не логіниться. Гугл бачить всі сайти з позиції аноніма. Наразі він бачить лише [оце](http://archive.is/ySUZd) (а може й це не бачити).

(Взагалі пошукові роботи не відправляють POST-форми, якщо вже трішки вдаватися в деталі.)